# Does the Apple App Store allow release and auto-update when the buildNumber is increased but the version number stays the same?

Tags: ios

Let's say I have an app that is version "3.0.8". It has the buildNumber 14. If I fix a bug and increment to buildNumber 15, am I able to release this under the same version (3.0.8)? And will users with auto-updates enabled on buildNumber 15 receive updates to build 15?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should bump the major, minor or patch numbers in order to be able to publish a new version.

Here you have the apple doc regarding - **Uploading builds overview**: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev82a6a9d79